# Is my simple edit enough to salvage this question?

Tags: discussion

I don't always vote to reopen questions, but when I do, I post about it on meta. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195280/hide-add-to-cart-button-in-opencart-3-if-price-0) offers a clear enough goal along with the code that was tried and the result: *"It didn't work"* – which in this case is clear as day since the goal was to hide something and it didn't get hidden.

Is this a case of over zealous close voters or is there truly something wrong with the question?

Comment: Do note that the code was added *after* the question was closed.

Comment: @user202729 - I had totally not noticed that.  Makes way more sense now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was closed long before any code was added at all. More than half a day, in fact.

This was what the question body looked like at the time it was closed, before it was ever edited:

> Hide Add to cart button in opencart 3 if price equal 0
>
> Hello everyone,
>
> I need a solution to hide "add to cart" button from product page, category page, search page, tag page and other listing pages when the product price is zero.
>
> Thank you for your support.

No, I didn't mistakenly copy the title along with the body — the author did. (Which you've finally edited out.)

I don't blame any of the close voters for voting to close instead of trying to salvage the question.

Comment: my mistake - I didn't notice the order of events in the timeline.  thanks for pointing that out